# Use Google (Universal) Analytics values to build/enhance your page

Tags: php, google-analytics

With all new things Google Analytics is tracking (age, gender, interests..) it would be great to use those variables to build/enhance your page.

For example: if the visitor is assumed to be a male, show a picture of a male next to testimonials (same for female), use a larger font when the assumed age is above 50, etc. This can really give a boost to your conversion ratio.

Is it possible to get/use these values? Like loading them into a session cookie/var on the first visit.

I can't find anything regarding this topic on Google..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. Google does not provide a way for you to get the user's demographics.